# A bug in the official libsigc++ 2.0 example?

Tags: c++, libsigc++

I was following the official documentation for `libsigc++-2.0` and I found [this example](https://developer.gnome.org/libsigc++-tutorial/stable/ch02.html):

```
class AlienDetector
{
public:
    AlienDetector();

    void run();

    sigc::signal<void> signal_detected;
};

void warn_people()
{
    cout << "There are aliens in the carpark!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    AlienDetector mydetector;
    mydetector.signal_detected.connect( sigc::ptr_fun(warn_people) );

    mydetector.run();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see both the `run()` function and the constructor for the `AlienDetector` class are not defined and therefore this code shouldn't compile ( but the doc takes for granted the fact that this code will work ).

Even more strange is the fact that if I define both `run()` and the constructor for the class, I can't see the effect of the library anyway, apparently the signal doesn't work and when `run` is called in the `main` no slot is activated.

I am forgetting about something here ? How this thing should be re-written ?

Comment: The example code contains the [run function later on](https://developer.gnome.org/libsigc++-tutorial/stable/ch03.html). The example does look to be incomplete, though.

Comment: @Petesh so why it suggests to compile and run that code knowing the fact that it's incomplete ?

Comment: At a wild guess, incomplete documentation. You are free to log an issue about it so that it can be addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation seems to be incomplete.

The most basic version of the code should look like:

```
AlienDetector::AlienDetector() {}

void AlienDetector::run() {
    sleep(3); // wait for aliens
    signal_detected.emit(); // panic
}
```

I've posted a fully functional make-based example [on github](https://github.com/petesh/sigc--2.0-example), example1.cpp is the first example, example2.cpp is one using a member function.

Comment: Could you publish a more complete example involving 2 different class wired together with signals and slots ?

Comment: are you trying to use gtkmm? or understand this library?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how libsigc++ works and how to use it.

Comment: I've put examples on github that should show it's basic use for plain old functions, and member functions

Answer (score 0):

To be more precise, that particular page of documentation is correct and presented as intended, but with a key link missing. I'll get to what is missing after reviewing what is there. The code that is listed as one block in the question is presented as two blocks in the documentation:

> Here's my class:
>
> ```
> <first code block, which
> declares AlienDetector>
> ```
>
> Here's your code that uses it:
>
> ```
> <second code block, which
> defines warn_people() and
> main()>
> ```

This split is an important detail. The learning scenario being presented is one where you have to write code that interfaces with a certain class. In this sort of scenario, the information you have to work with is the declaration of that class, not the implementation of it (the header file, not the source). Hence, the first code block provides the declaration without code for the functions. The presentation appropriately leaves out the details that you should ignore at the moment.

**The omission** comes a bit further down the page:

> To compile this example, use:
>
> ```
> g++ example1.cc -o example1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs sigc++-2.0`
> ```

Hold on—"example1.cc"? What is that? You might notice that the page did not say how to create `example1.cc`. While it is somewhat natural to assume that one should copy the code from the page into this file, that is not what was intended. The author had intended that `example1.cc` be a pre-made file (with the missing function implementations) that would accompany the text. Somehow this file, and the others referenced later in the tutorial, never made it into the published product.

This omission has been known for a while (see some [mail](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/libsigc-list/2003-October/msg00004.html) [archives](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/libsigc-list/2003-November/msg00025.html)), but has not attracted the right sort of attention to fix it. (The tutorial was updated a few months after the emails I linked to, but apparently not to add the missing example files.) In the linked emails, the author provided a link to get the missing files, but in the decade+ since then, the link has expired.

Fortunately, Petesh has provided a longer-lived source for some example files in the older answer here. (As for me, I'm just being overly detailed and precise. Too bad I got lost when trying to figure out where this issue could be logged so that it could be addressed, or at least tracked.)